# How many 6-digit numbers can be formed using the digits 1,2,3,4,5,6 and 7, so that the digits do not repeat and the terminal digits should be even?

Tags: combinatorics

We know that the last digit should be even --> 2,4 or 6

Also, a digit should only be used only once --> 7.6.5.4.3.2 (let us call it 'var1')

So, shouldn't the answer be (var1)x3 ? ( 3  for each number ending with 2, 4 and 6 respectively)

Can someone point out any mistake(s) I may have made ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2$ would be the correct answer if we didn't have the final digit being even constraint. But as we do, it makes sense to think of the number in two separate parts: the last digit, and then the first five.

As you say, there are three choices for the terminal digit. But then, for the first five digits, we don't have a choice of seven digits any more - we have the choice of six ($\{1,3,5,7 \}$ or one of the unused two even digits). So the number of options for the first five is $6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2 = 720$.

The final answer is therefore $3 \cdot 720 = 2160$ possible numbers.

EDIT: Just for fun, I confirmed the answer in Python, so the question can also be answered programmatically, though the above method is much preferable.

```
count = 0
for i in range(100000, 999999 + 1):
    temp = list(int(x) for x in str(i))
    if len(temp) == len(set(temp)) and temp[-1] % 2 == 0:
        if "0" not in str(i) and "8" not in str(i) and "9" not in str(i):
            count += 1
print("count =", count)

Output: count = 2160
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help from the comment, if you still fancy reading the answer below, you will get the same answer.

If they used $2$ even numbers from $3$ even numbers in the first $5$ digits and order them, after then they pick up $3$ numbers from the $4$ odd numbers and put them into the remain $3$ positions and need to order them.

$T_1 = (3C2 * 5C2 * 2P1) *(4C3 * 3P3$): 1440

If they choose $1$ even numbers from $3$ even numbers and put them into the first $5$ digits, and they pick up $4$  numbers from $4$ odd numbers and put them into remaining $4$ positions. And they pick up $1$ even number from the $2$ even numbers.

$T_2$ =  ($3C1 * 5C1) * (4C4 * 4P4) * 2C1$ ):720

$T = T_1 + T_2$.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  While you have not specified how you arrived at each factor, I will assume $\binom{3}{1}$ counts the number of ways of selecting the even units digit.  If two of the first five digits are even, you must use both of the remaining even digits (making your factor of $\binom{2}{1}$ incorrect) and three of the four odd digits.  Once you choose these five digits, you need to order them.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig Thank you for the comment. I stated if I pick up 1 even number from 3 even numbers, there are 5 places you can choose in the first 5 digits ($\binom{3}{1}$ * $\binom{5}{1}$). Next, if I picked up 1 number from 2 remain even numbers, there are 4 places you can choose in 4 remain digits($\binom{2}{1}$ * $\binom{4}{1})$. And we have to put 3 odd numbers from 4 odd numbers and order them($\binom{4}{3}$ * 3P3) and we have 1 remaining even number $\binom{1}{1}$. ($\binom{3}{1}$ * $\binom{5}{1}$) * ($\binom{2}{1}$ * $\binom{4}{1})$ * ($\binom{4}{3}$ * 3P3)  * $\binom{1}{1}$.

Comment: Your second case is correct.  For the first case, choose the units digit, choose the position of the smaller even number that remains, choose the position of the other even number, choose three of the four odd digits, then arrange them in the remaining positions.  $$3 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot \binom{4}{3} \cdot 3! = 1440$$  You obtained twice that number since you counted numbers such as $312456$ twice, once when you placed $2$ in the third position and then placed $4$ in the fourth position and once when you placed $4$ in the fourth position and then placed $2$ in the third position.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks so much for the advice. I over-counted since I mixed “At first, I will put an even number from the three evens into position x and after then will choose an even number from the two and put it into position y” with “At first An even number was chosen at position x and now I choose an even number from the rest two”. I should have done $\binom{3}{2} * \binom{5}{2} * 2P1  \binom{4}{3} * 3P3 = 1440$ at once. Thank you  for taking time for correcting.